# How importing actually works in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, importerror

In my working directory, I have python3 files like this

```
/Path/to/cwd/main.py
/Path/to/cwd/Folder/one.py
/Path/to/cwd/Folder/two.py
```

So I had a main.py file like this

```
import Folder.one as one
#Do something
```

In one.py I had code like this

```
import two
#Some functions defined locally utilizing functions written in two.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Code for testing Functions
```

When I run one.py, it runs fine. But when I run main.py, it throws an error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'two'

Ideally, I would not be expecting such an error at all.

It worked when I changed the import statement from `import two` to `import Folder.two`, which works. But I would like to do this in some other way without affecting such import statements much. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the python interpreter to know what directories contain code to be loaded, you need to include a `__init__.py` file.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4116384/6372042) to learn more about how to import packages.

In the case of your second import, to access that method you would need to use this syntax.

`from .two import *`

Comment: My python version is 3.6.9, it's not needed for my version of python. Anyway I tried it but didn't work.

Comment: And as I said, the error is at `import two` in one.py and not in main.py file

Comment: I have edited the answer with some help for that, have a look at [this article](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/#relative-imports) to learn more about relative imports